# A Strange Error Caused By "arm-linux-gcc" And "sim-panalyzer" Locates In Glibc Function "dl_aux_init"

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, simulator, glibc

I write a simplist c-language program which has no extra functional code and library dependency:

```
void main()
{
}
```

Save it as "Test.c" and I compile it with "arm-linux-gcc" for arm architect and ouput an elf format file "Test", the command is "**arm-linux-gcc Test.c -o Test -static**".
  Then I use power simulator tool "Sim-Panalyzer" to estimate the power of file "Test",and the  echo information shows "***fatal:non-speculative fault (2) detected @ 0x00013c58***". 
  So I use command "**readelf -S Test**" and find the address is in segment ".text", and then use command "**arm-linux-objdump Test -Sl -j .text > a.txt**" to ouput the infomation in a file "a.txt". I locate the address and learn the infomation here:

```
   13c48:   1affffd4    bne 13ba0 <_dl_aux_init+0x8c>
   13c4c:   e352000f    cmp r2, #15
   13c50:   e59d201c    ldr r2, [sp, #28]
   13c54:   e59d3018    ldr r3, [sp, #24]
   13c58:   e5892000    str r2, [r9]
```

It's obvious here that the error occurs in the function "**dl_aux_init**" in gcc library "glibc-2.9/elf/dl-support.c" but I have no idea about how to handle this bug. I can't believe the error in the glibc, so I hope someone could help me find the reason leading this error. Is there something wrong with the use of "Sim-Panalyzer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is strange, but the reason is that I used the **latest** "arm-linux-gcc" **version**(4.3.2) and caused this problem. I change the tool version to 2.95.3 which is download from site http://ftp.arm.linux.org.uk/pub/armlinux/toolchain/, and then everything goes ok! It's obvious that there is nothing with the tool "sim-panalyzer2.0".